# CakePhp 3 use different configuration unit test

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, configuration

I have a problem with my CakePHP application for testing.

I want a different value in test for a constant like this :

```
<?php
if ( IS_TEST )
    define('MY_CONST', 'value1');
else
    define('MY_CONST', 'value2');
```

I tried with the class Configure but I have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

In test/bootstrap.php

```
define('_TEST', true);
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/bootstrap.php';
```

And in config/bootstrap.php

```
if ( ! defined('_TEST') )
    define('_TEST', false);

define('FILES_DIR',
    (_TEST)
         ? 'tests' . DS . 'files' . DS
         : 'files' . DS );
```